# Unity DI, multiple named instances

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have this simplified construction of my problem. I have multiple named instances and as you can see the number of the registrations of IBusinessLogic is increased with each added parameter. Is there elegant way to achieve that below without the need to have so many RegisterType for IBusinessLogic.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings1>("settings1");
        container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings2>("settings2");

        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository1 settings1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1")));
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository1 settings2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2")));
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository2 settings1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1")));
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository2 settings2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2")));

        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1 settings1 repository1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository1 settings1")));
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1 settings2 repository1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository1 settings1")));

        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1 settings1 repository2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository2 settings2")));
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1 settings2 repository2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository2 settings2")));

        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2 settings1 repository1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository1 settings1")));
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2 settings2 repository1", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository1 settings1")));

        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2 settings1 repository2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings1"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository2 settings2")));
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2 settings2 repository2", new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>("settings2"), new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>("repository2 settings2")));

        string inputParam1 = "logic1";
        string inputParam2 = "settings2";
        string inputParam3 = "repository1";

        var instance = container.Resolve<IBusinessLogic>(inputParam1 + " " + inputParam2 + " " + inputParam3);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I found alternative way but I have to specify explicitly each override in the dependency graph

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings1>("settings1");
        container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings2>("settings2");

        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository1");
        container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository2>("repository2");

        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1");
        container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2");

        string inputParam1 = "logic1";
        string inputParam2 = "settings1";
        string inputParam3 = "repository1";

        var instance = container.Resolve<IBusinessLogic>(inputParam1, new DependencyOverrides()
            {
                {typeof(ISettings),container.Resolve<ISettings>(inputParam2)},
                {typeof(IRepository),container.Resolve<IRepository>(inputParam3, new DependencyOverrides() 
                    { 
                        {typeof(ISettings),container.Resolve<ISettings>(inputParam2)} 
                    })
                 },
            });
    }
}
```

What I really need is to tell the container - Resolve IBusinessLogic and use "settings1" named instance everywhere in the dependency graph where you need ISettings instance. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you explain this part *"Resolve IBusinessLogic and use "settings1" named instance everywhere in the dependency graph where you need ISettings instance"*? If you just need "settings1", why register "settings2"?  Also, can you explain which clients (classes) in your code require which dependencies?

Comment: Is there a `BusinessLogic2` in your code? You seem to have only `BusinessLogic1`.

Comment: I modified the code and added BusinessLogic2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings1>("settings1");
container.RegisterType<ISettings, Settings2>("settings2");

container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository1>("repository1");
container.RegisterType<IRepository, Repository2>("repository2");

container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic1>("logic1");
container.RegisterType<IBusinessLogic, BusinessLogic2>("logic2");

string inputParam1 = "logic1";
string inputParam2 = "settings1";
string inputParam3 = "repository1";

var result = container.Resolve<IBusinessLogic>(inputParam1,
    new DependencyOverride<ISettings>(new ResolvedParameter<ISettings>(inputParam2)),
    new DependencyOverride<IRepository>(new ResolvedParameter<IRepository>(inputParam3)));
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the answer I was looking for!